# Typescript: How to declare type list of dictionaries?

Tags: arrays, typescript, list, dictionary, types

I want to declare a list of dictionaries where the key is a `string` and the value is a `number.`

How might I modify the current code, see below, that declares `count` as a a list of strings.

`const dict: string[] = [];`

Answer (score 3):

> dictionary where the key is a string and the value is a number.

This is [a `Record` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type). In this case:

```
Record<string, number>
```

Or an index signature would work as well:

```
{ [myKey: string]: number }
```

Then just add a `[]` to the end of either of those to make it an array of those objects.

```
const dict: Record<string, number>[] = [
  { a: 123, b: 456 },
  { c: 789 },
]
```